# Windows 7 moving hundreds of files

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-transfer

I have ~600 files each in a folder (alone), in a folder (alone), in a folder (alone),(repeat x8),... joint parent folder. Is there a way to get rid of this absurd structure of useless sub-directories that won't take 3 hours? I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: if you are copying the files to a location on the same disk, then the copy takes almost no time, because it just changes the filesystem metadata to reflect the parent directory change. as such, any solution should not take multiple hours. I'd write a powershell script for doing it in windows, but you could use python or whatever other scripting languages are available to traverse the tree and copy any files to a directory.

Comment: Windows has no problem you moving multiple groups of hundreds of files  at once.

Comment: Just be sure that the files in the separate folders do not have the same file name or else you may overwrite the existing file with that same file name when copying obviously. I'm sure you could batch something out to do this but you can do this from Windows Explorer just fine with a Ctrl+A --> right-click --> copy of the files in the folder to copy and then a right-click --> paste to paste those into the folder you are copying them to. Once the copy is completed, then select all the files in the folder which were copied over successfully and delete them; this may be better than using cut.

Comment: I've tried several solutions (XCOPY, C# program) and consistently get an error letting me know that the paths are too long. Gee... thanks error message. I agree completely. That's the problem I'm trying to fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I wrote a python script for this kind of thing. Its called volcano, because it causes all the files in the directory to erupt, and spill out into the folder root. Obviously something you want to be careful with. only pass it a directory that you want to erupt.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#volcano

import os, sys, shutil


def main():
    for a in sys.argv:
        arg = os.path.normpath(a)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(arg, False):
            for f in files:
                src = os.path.join(root, f)
                fname =  os.path.split(src)[1]
                try:
                    shutil.move(src, os.path.join(arg, fname))
                    print "moved %s to %s" %(src, os.path.join(arg, fname))
                except Exception, e:
                    print "Error moving file %s to %s" %(src, os.path.join(arg, fname))
                    print "Exception: ", e 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot. I wrote a short C# program to do it, but the paths were too long. (Same error when I tried using XCOPY).

Comment: if you are having path length problems, look into the `subst` command in cmd. it will let you assign a path to a location like "b:\". see here under the heading  "method 1": https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/Windows_File_Paths_Longer_Than_255_Characters

Comment: Thanks Frank Thomas! The 'too long' path was short enough that abbreviating the full parent using substr worked!